# MongoDB Service fails caused by corrupt data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, panic, wiredtiger

I made a node/express website based on a mongodb a couple of months ago and it all worked like a charm. Then suddenly, one month ago, I couldn't start the mongod.exe. I still haven't found an answer so I hope to get one in this forum.

Somehow the files in the data folder are corrupt. When I take the files from an earlier state or the default files from mongodb the mongod.exe can start normal.

There are pictures in the attachment from the data with which the mongod.exe won't start and the error. There is something like:

> "WiredTiger encountered an illegal file format or internal value. WiredTiger library panic"

Image of the mongod.exe error:
[image: Image of the mongod.exe error]

Data folder of the mongodb collection with which mongod.exe can't start:
[image: Data folder of the mongodb collection with which mongod.exe can't start]

Comment: Is your question how those files could get corrupted? That could be any one (or more) of: bad RAM, bad disk, bad shutdown, MongoDB processed killed ungracefully, who knows. I would start running some hardware diagnostics.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you for the answer! Unfortunatly, it's throwing the same error on every computer. Do you know how to repair the files?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it myself, but when you google _"wiredtiger corrupt"_ you find various pages that may be of help (like [this one](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/)).